# NLTK pos_tag module returns LookupError

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

[image]

[image]

The details are on the above.
I run it on Jupiter notebook, and get the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

On the terminal:

```
python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger
```

or in Python

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

---

## In Long

Firstly, please update your NLTK version to version 3.2.5, on the command line (Use `sudo` if necessary):

```
pip install -U nltk
```

Now you can try using the `pos_tag` function again and you should see a more helpful error message:

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> pos_tag(['foo', 'bar'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 133, in pos_tag
    tagger = _get_tagger(lang)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 97, in _get_tagger
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py", line 140, in __init__
    AP_MODEL_LOC = 'file:'+str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 673, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource averaged_perceptron_tagger not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

  Searched in:
    - '/Users/alvas/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'

**********************************************************************
```

---

Note that the `punkt` resource is used for `word_tokenize()` but the `pos_tag()` function requires the `averaged_perceptron_tagger` model.

So, on the terminal, do:

```
python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger
```

or in Python

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```